# Will mapping in RethinkDB compute the same thing multiple times for same value?

Tags: java, rethinkdb

I am using `RethinkDB` Java driver and wanted to computer Mean Deviation for every value of a particular field.

So, I wrote this code:

```
public static ReqlExpr avgdev(ReqlExpr expr, String field) {
        return expr.map(
                entry -> entry.g("parent_document").g(field).sub(expr.avg(row -> row.g("documents").g(field)))
        );
    }
```

As you can see, the average is computed multiple times. For computations like this, will RethinkDB automatically make sure that the average is computed only once, or should I manually compute the mean once and then use it for computing the deviation?

I ask this because the design pattern that I'm using may change significantly in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RethinkDB doesn't do any sort of common subexpression elimination right now.  I would recommend factoring out the common subexpression with `do` (so something like `expr.avg(...).do(avg -> expr.map(...))`).